# How to remove space from the xml which is now made as a String?

Tags: java, xml

Sample.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>    
<note> 
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from> 
  <heading>Reminder</heading> 
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
</note>
```

Method:xmlToStringStreamExample()

```
public String xmlToStringStreamExample () {
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
    InputStream is =
      new ByteArrayInputStream(ClassName.Class().getClassLoader().
        getResource("Sample.xml")); // read it with BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            x.append(line);
        }
    } catch(IOException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return x.toString();
}
```

This method and xml are **correct**. However while printing the value of `x` I'm getting spaces. And I want to remove these spaces. I tried `x.repalceAll("\\\s", "");` but this did not work - the spaces were still there. I also tried `x.replace(" ", "");` but this too did not remove the spaces. Could someone help me on this? Spaces are included when the next line includes tags.

Comment: Did you just do `x.replace(...)` or `x = x.replace(...)`? Strings are immutable. You have to assign the result of the substitution to a variable.

Comment: try this `System.out.println(x.toString().replace(" ",""));`

Comment: x.toString().replace(" ",""); too did not work.

Comment: Since reading the file into a string buffer works, according to your question, and the problem is with replacing spaces, maybe you should post _that_ code instead (and also how you are printing the replaced string).

Comment: The method and the comments you wrote are kind of strange. First: your method is not returning anything, second you say you do x.replace, but x is a Stringbuilder so it hasn't got any replace method in the way you use it

Comment: Please share the code you are using to print this string, the code which replace spaces. And share the final outcome as well which have spaces.

Comment: It's also a bit odd that you're manipulating XML as text. Not necessarily unreasonable, but normally folks would use APIs designed for the purpose.

Comment: Could it be that your string has linefeeds like \n or \r and the representation is showing them as spaces?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> <note>  <to>Tove</to> <from>Jani </from>  <heading>Reminder</heading> <body>Don't forget me this weekend!      </body> </note>  -----This is the value of "x". Could you help me to remove the spaces? The spaces vary.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the spaces? and what spaces are you are you talking about?  What are you doing with the return value of x after this method?

Comment: Can I ask an obvious question. Why do you want to remove the spaces? If you are trying to normalize it for comparison in a junit test you would be much better off using something like XMLUnit.

Comment: I used this code in my Junit. But it has nothing to do with the Junit. I need the value of x for printing them on the screen. Is there a way to remove a varying lengths of spaces from a string? Or should I start writing a new piece of code to remove the different lengths of spaces?

Comment: Where in the code are you printing x and the string?  Post that, everything you have posted here is irrelevant to what you are trying to print

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>[space] [space] [space] <note>[space]  <to>Tove[space] </to> [space] [space] <from>Jani [space] </from>[space] 
 <heading>Reminder[space] [space] </heading> [space] [space] <body>Don't forget me this weekend! </body> [space] [space] [space] </note> ---------I cannot pla the space in the comment so I have used[space]in between which denotes the space in the line.Sorry for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **x.append(line.trim());** instead of x.append(line);

```
FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] downloadStream = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            fi.read(downloadStream);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(downloadStream); // read it with BufferedReader
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                x.append(line.trim());
            }
```

Comment: I tried this before itself. It was throwing a SAXParseException.

Comment: This code which I used is a part of the Junit test cases that I'm writing. Ther I have included the xml file in src/test/resources and the method is included in a package within  src/test/java. So this won't work when I pass the file as mentioned in your code.Thanks for this. But is there any other way to remove varying lengths of spaces from a string?

Comment: How could it throw a SAXParseException none of the code you have shown us is using a SAX parser?

Comment: I posted the method and the xml file so that you will get to know where I got the string from. My question was: is there any other way to remove varying lengths of spaces from a string? Could you help me on this??

Comment: In this way, I don't have a clue.

Comment: As far as I concerned, you have an XML file and a method which reads the file and makes a string, also there is a problem with the string. Ok, you should write a mock method which return a simple xml format string, for example 'return "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>    
<note> 
  <to>Tove</to>  
  <from>Jani</from> 
  <heading>Reminder</heading> 
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body> 
</note>"'

Comment: then test it by your parser to find what is an accurate string for your parser. after send both accurate string and orginal xml file to me.